# How can I force the display of image "handles" in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

In order to select images in Microsoft Word documents you need to get the cursor just right so that it turns into the "+" arrow icon, at which point you can click to select the image.

When your cursor is *not* in exactly the right spot you see something like this (note that the letter "m" shown in the picture is an image, not a font):

[image: Image not selectable]

When your cursor *is* in an appropriate spot you see something like this:

[image: Image is selectable]

For simple images with relatively straight and simple borders, it's easy; you hover over the image and you get the "+" arrow.  But for smaller, more intricate images with many sides, thin borders or perhaps transparency it's often madness as you move your cursor all over the image struggling to find the teenie little spot that Word deems is selectable.

Is there some means of enabling the display of "handles" (maybe wrong term) around images *before* you select them, so you can see the selectable spots without hunting and pecking for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images in Word documents are automatically selected when you insert them, and it is quite easy to deselect and select them. It gets difficult when the *text wrapping* is set to *Behind Text* as you'd have to hover the mouse over the edges of the image to be able to select it.

One work around is to use the **Select Objects** tool from **Home** tab > **Editing** group > **Select** and your mouse pointer will automatically turn into a four-headed arrow and you can easily hover on images to select them.

You can also use the **Selection Pane...** again from the **Home** tab > **Editing** group > **Select** which opens a pane on the right side of the document window and lists all the images on the document allowing you to easily *click on images on the list to select them*.

[image]

Comment: What a good and beautiful answer, @msPeachy!